# JDBC error : can not issue executeupdate() for selects

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Good day ,

While I am trying to update data after inserting new ones in the database,

This message is showing for me

```
can not issue executeupdate() for selects
```

I have checked [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-update-records.htm) and [codejava](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/jdbc-tutorial-sql-insert-select-update-and-delete-examples) and the codes for both update and select are the same and the program is issuing the statement above

Here is my codes

```
     String Sql="Select * from training where trainID=? "; 
        try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hr","root","MZaa8891@");
        ps= con.prepareStatement(Sql);
        ps.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
        rs =ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()){
           jTextField2.setText(rs.getString("traTitle"));
       }
        }
        catch (Exception e){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    } 
         String Sql="Select * from training where traTitle =? "; 
        try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hr","root","MZaa8891@");
        ps= con.prepareStatement(Sql);
        ps.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
        rs =ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()){
           jTextField2.setText(rs.getString("trainID"));
       }
        }
        catch (Exception e){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
 String Sql= "UPDATE training SET traTitle ='"+ jTextField2.getText()+"', Type = "+(String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"', SDate = '"+sqlDate+"', Edate = '"+sqlDate2+"', location = '"+jTextField3.getText()+"',provider = '"+(String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"',related = '"+jTextArea1.getText()+"',benefits = '"+jTextArea2.getText()+"'important = '"+jTextArea3.getText()+"' WHERE trainID = "+jTextField1.getText()+"";
     try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hr","root","MZaa8891@");
       Statement st = con.createStatement();
      int i =ps.executeUpdate();
        if (i>0)
        {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data is Saved");
        }
        else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data is not Saved");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Any Solution ?

Comment: You're not updating anything with a select, so use `executeQuery` instead.

Comment: You are missing a `ps= con.prepareStatement(Sql);` before your call to `executeUpdate`, so you are executing the previous SELECT query again .

Comment: You're also completely misunderstanding how to use `PreparedStatements` in your update. You're supposed to set the values with `setString(1, jTextField2.getText())` just like you did with the selects.

Comment: This is not an 'issue'. It is documented behaviour.

Comment: I have used executeQuery in select and executeUpdate in update as I mentioned above so where shall I change

Comment: how is it behavior ?

Comment: How is it *not* behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();
int i = ps.executeUpdate();
```

The problem is here. You are creating a new, unused, `Statement`, and then trying to call `executeUpdate()` on the previously prepared statement, which was a SELECT.

This would have been avoided by correctly scoping the variables concerned as method-local. None of them should be instance or static members.

Comment: I have created local variable as you told me but now another error which is Java.nullPointerException

Comment: Good. That is progress. I would expect any competent Java programmer to be able to sort out an NPE without further assistance. In any case you can't seriously expect further help without posting the current code.